# Disable auto-dimming based on screen content

Tags: android, react-native

I have an issue where the font color in a screen of my app changes from white to almost gray. After hours of experimenting I was able to find out that this is caused by Android's auto-dimming feature.

A page of mine starts of as a pretty dark background with a spinner. When data is fetched have plenty cards onscreen(all with white background).

This leads the color of the font in my header to change form grayish to (as intended) white. The change is extreme and very noticeable.

Is there a way to turn off this feature?

Comment: [This post indicates that it is not possible to overwrite this behaviour.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/how-can-i-disable-auto-dimming-of-the-screen)

Comment: In case someone has this issue, I have a feature in my Display settings, "Economic  Backlight", that causes this behavior. The feature might be useful but in my case its interfering with my ui. Font changing colors is pretty annoying